# Can´t add header to MassTransit message from OperationContext?

Tags: c#, wcf, masstransit, nettcpbinding, operationcontext

I am trying to add a header to a Masstransit message containing information from the currently logged user on a WCF Web application.

So at my web app, I have the following when the app starts:

```
IBusControl bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
{
    cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/test"), r =>
    {
        //...
    });

    cfg.ConfigureSend(
        s => s.UseSendExecute(
            c => c.Headers.Set(Constants.UserInfo, 
           OperationContext.Current.Channel.Extensions.Find<PropertyUserInfo>().Info)));
});
```

> I am using an IoC container to create `IBusControl` only once in the application (singleton scope), then IBusControl gets injected into the Web service.
>
> Note that `OperationContext.Current` does not exists when I am creating the servicebus, **I am expecting the lambda `c= > c.Headers.Set(...)` to be called within the request context**

Now, when the user makes a request, I am using a request-response pattern (although I dont think this matters)

```
var requestClient = _bus.CreateRequestClient<AddTicketRequest, AddTicketResponse>(uri, timeout);
var response = requestClient.Request(requestMessage);
```

The problem is, when this code is executed, and Masstransit tries to add the header to the message, `OperationContext.Current` is `null` as apparently it is running on a different thread then the user call.

Oddly enough, eventually Masstransit starts to call `UseSendExecute` from the right thread, and everything starts to work. And I have to restart IIS to replicate the bug again (!?).

Has anybody ever had this problem ? thanks.

*I know I can add the Header when publishing the message, but I wanted to have all messages originated from the web application to have this header, and was expecting have it set up globally.*

Comment: Why are you not setting headers on sending the request, where you are in the context, so you can use local variable for a closure?

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev, thx, I guess I could set header when calling `CreateRequestClient`, but I´ll have to do it for every single call. I want the userinfo to be processed on endpoint filters (e.g. access permission)

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev Is that what you would do ?

Comment: besides, I have other use cases with `_bus.Publish`, routing slip, etc. I would have to do that for each one

Comment: I think this issue is more ideological, it is not about threads but more about being in the context of web request when you send messages. If you use an IoC container, you can probably get some context information from there, since usually you have encapsulated context for each request.

Comment: I do use an IoC container, but the  `IBusControl` was beeing created only once in Singleton Scope, for the entire application, so I did not have request context to pass as closure to `cfg.ConfigureSend`, I´ve updated the question

Comment: Eventually, i´ve created a wrapper arround `IBusControl`, so I could intercept the messages, but it just doesn´t feel right.

Answer (score 1):

The issue https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/921 looks related. I'll go with the same workaround, and I will work with a wrapper around IBusControl.