# MassTransit: How to set custom headers on all outgoing messages via Dependency Injection?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm using MassTransit in a NetCore API.

On each incoming request to my API, I have middleware running that takes some user information from the incoming HTTP request and sets values on a scoped object I've called `CallContext`.

I'm able to inject this `CallContext` anywhere I need it to find out who / what is making the current call and perform appropriate actions.

Many of my backend services publish and / or send messages via MassTransit. I'd like all outgoing messages to have a custom "CallContext" header so that consumers are able to determine who or what generated a message.

At first I considered using an Observer to accomplish this, but the docs [here](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/observers.html) discourage this:

> Observers should not be used to modify or intercept messages. To
> intercept messages (to either add headers or modify message content),
> create a new or use an existing middleware component.

The documentation for custom middleware [here](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/middleware/custom.html) is unclear regarding use with a DI Container. All of the samples I could find look similar to this:

```
configurator.AddPipeSpecification(new ExceptionLoggerSpecification<T>());
```

With the use of the `new` keyword kicking off the registration process, it's not possible to resolve my `CallContext` dependency from the DI container.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45945303/can%C2%B4t-add-header-to-masstransit-message-from-operationcontext#) question from 2017 and [this](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/921) GitHub issue are attempting to implement the same thing, but I can't find any clear guidance about how to accomplish the same thing in recent (7.x) versions of MassTransit.

**How can custom middleware be implemented such that the middleware is able to resolve scoped object instances from the .NET Core DI container?**

Comment: Have you looked at [scoped filters](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/middleware/scoped.html)? These should allow you to do what you want.

Comment: Yeah that did the trick. If you want to write a short answer with that link, I'll accept it. Thanks!